# Fix internal links in JS

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, rhino, e4x

I just created a script which extracts the article out of a webpage via server-side JS. (If your interested: it's used for http://pipes.yahoo.com/fb55/expandr .)

I just got a little problem with internal links. Some pages include links like:

```
/subfolder/subpage.html
```

What I would need to do is fixing them and setting there root, like this:

```
protocol://secondlevel.firstlevel/subfolder/subpage.html
```

I'm using E4X for processing the page. I don't want to show my current creepy try, it's buggy and slow. Does anybody have a solution for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to rewrite them with some Regular Expression:

```
var baseUrl = "http://somesite.com/somepage"
var root = baseUrl.match(/^[^:]+:\/\/[^\/]+\//)[0];
// "http://somesite.com/"

var HTML = "<a href='/testing'>test</a> and <a class='test' href=\"/foo/bar\"> </a>";

HTML.replace(/<a [^>]*href=["']\/([^'"]+)["']/ig, function (whole, url) {
  return whole.replace("/"+url, root+url);
});

// "<a href='http://somesite.com/testing'>test</a> and <a class='test' href=\"http://somesite.com/foo/bar\"> </a>"
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, even if there is some performance to gain. (But it's way better than my code.)

Thank you!